# Building a specific rank chart with two "bars" for each X value in R

Tags: r, graph, visualization

Dear Stack overflow community,

I am new to R and I would like to build a very specific chart but struggle with the ggplot language. Basically, this is a toy version of my dataset given by the `dput` command:

```
structure(list(rank = structure(1:15, levels = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", 
"71", "72", "73", "74", "75"), class = "factor"), year = c("1986", 
"1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", 
"1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986"), name = c("SectionA", 
"SectionB", "SectionC", "SectionD", "SectionE", "SectionF", 
"SectionG", "SectionH", "SectionI", "SectionJ", "SectionK", 
"SectionL", "SectionM", "SectionN", "SectionO"), section = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), id = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", 
"ID5", "ID6", "ID7", "ID8", "ID9", "ID10", "ID11", "ID12", "ID13", "ID14")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My dataset stores information about different sections and subsections of a survey have evolved over time. Two challenges arise from this:

- One section in Year 1 can be a subsection in Year 2.
- One section in Year 1 can have another name in Year 2 while containing the exact same type of questions inside.

To address problem 1, the variable "section" is here to assess whether the section name (contained in variable "name" is a section (== 0) or a subsection of the last section (== 1). Problem 2 is solved thanks to the variable ID that more or less standardizes section names that share similar thematic characteristics.

Finally, the variable "rank" stores the position of the section in the questionnaire. So the first section of the questionnaire will have rank == 1.

What I would like to do is a chart with, on the X-axis, my **year variable** (1986, 1992, 1998...) and on the Y-axis, my **rank variable**. Each year would contain two vertical bars: On the left, all the sections position (section == 0), and on the right, all the subsections position (section == 1). Since there is a rank variable for both sections and subsections included, there will never be two points with the same Y coordinates for one year. The trick is that I would like sections and subsections sharing similar "id" values across time to have the same color, but I would like the writing to be the ones given by "name" so that everyone sees how the wording of the questionnaire have changed for a similar topic, even if the order have changed.

Since I cannot describe it better with words, I did a small representation of what I would like to do on Paint:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9rcM.png)

In this example, you can see that section A in 1986 became section U in 1992 (say, for example, it went from "wealth description" to "wealth"). But since they would share the same standardized ID, they would appear in the same color.

I would really appreciate any help you could provide on this topic!

Best,

Comment: in your text you wrote about plotting two vertical bars per year; then in your paint sketch you have sketched zero bars, and seem to have a scatter or dot plot. can you clarify ?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't notice that bit. Indeed it's a dot plot that I want and not bars.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this can get you started

```
library(tidyverse)
df0 <- structure(list(rank = structure(1:15, levels = c(
  "1", "2", "3",
  "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",
  "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26",
  "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37",
  "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48",
  "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59",
  "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70",
  "71", "72", "73", "74", "75"
), class = "factor"), year = c(
  "1986",
  "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986",
  "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986"
), name = c(
  "SectionA",
  "SectionB", "SectionC", "SectionD", "SectionE", "SectionF",
  "SectionG", "SectionH", "SectionI", "SectionJ", "SectionK",
  "SectionL", "SectionM", "SectionN", "SectionO"
), section = structure(c(
  1L,
  1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L
), levels = c(
  "0",
  "1"
), class = "factor"), id = c(
  "ID1", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4",
  "ID5", "ID6", "ID7", "ID8", "ID9", "ID10", "ID11", "ID12", "ID13", "ID14"
)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df0$id <- factor(df0$id, levels = unique(df0$id))
df0$rank <- as.integer(as.character(df0$rank))
df0$year <- as.integer(as.character(df0$year))
df0$section <- as.integer(as.character(df0$section))

df2 <- bind_rows(
  df0,
  df0 |> mutate(year = 1987)
) |>
  mutate(xvar = year + ((section - .5) / 2))

ggplot(data = df2) +
  aes(
    x = xvar,
    y = rank,
    label = name,
    color = id
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(nudge_x = .2) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(from = 1986, to = 1987, by = 1),
    limits = c(1985, 1988)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:15, trans = scales::reverse_trans())
```